# What are the Required TBLPROPERTIES in a Hive External Table on a Kafka Stream on a Kerberized Server?

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, kerberos

I'm trying to create an external table on a kafka stream in hive kerberized environment. I've run into several issues while trying to run a simple SELECT * FROM [EXTERNAL KAFKA STREAM TABLE]. What are the required fields needed in a the tblproperties in my CREATE TABLE query?

Here's what I have:

1. kafka.bootstrap.servers
2. kafka.topic
3. kafka.consumer.sasl.kerberos.service.name
4. kafka.consumer.sasl.mechanism
5. kafka.consumer.sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol
6. kafka.consumer.sasl_ssl.gssapi.sasl.jaas.config
7. kafka.consumer.security.protocol
8. kafka.consumer.ssl.client.auth
9. kafka.consumer.ssl.protocol
10. kafka.consumer.ssl.truststore.location
11. kafka.consumer.ssl.truststore.password

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure those SSL or SASL properties are even accepted - you can see the source of the Properties defined here - https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/kafka-handler/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/kafka/KafkaTableProperties.java

The Kafka Kerberos principals come from the HiveConf, not Table Properties, it seems due to this commit, and cannot be overridden - https://github.com/apache/hive/commit/dcaeeb4722553f3256c9d3f5282cc82cae7bc9b4#diff-f206f68e2d1b5d396fa7f12830d98cbfR279

1. This code isn't ready until Hive 4.0.0 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20735
2. According to that code, `SASL_PLAINTEXT` is the only supported `security.protocol`
3. That section is loaded if “hadoop.security.authentication” is set to “kerberos” in the `core-site.xml` from the `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`

---

Other than those first few, though, `kafka.serde.class` can be added if your topic isn't using JSON, and the "inter.broker.protocol" isn't a valid consumer property anyway.

---

I'm not sure what would happen if Hive is Kerberized and Kafka is not